# How do I change an element.style's style? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, userscripts

Here is my html code I want to change the style of

```
<img src="linkremoved" style="
    height:45px;
    width:45px;
    margin-right:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;">
```

I can't seem to figure this out. I need this in a userscript form.

Comment: What kind of things have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pure javascript it's best to add an id:

```
<img id="myImage" src="linkremoved" style="height:45px;width:45px;margin-right:10px;-webkit-border-radius: 50%;-moz-border-radius: 50%;border-radius: 50%;">
```

and then use:

```
document.getElementById('myImage').style.height='50px';
```

If you can't add an id you'll need:

```
/**
 * Get an image by it's src.
 *
 * Returns the first image matching the src
 */
function getImageBySrc( src ) { 
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i in images) {
        if(images[i].getAttribute('src') == src) {
            return images[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// useage
var myImage = getImageBySrc( 'linkremoved' );
myImage.style.height='50px';
```

Comment: I cannot ad an Id to this. That's my issue.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect that. In future you should mention that kind of restriction in your question.